# How to mock.patch library function from within unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a module called `learning` that uses `random.uniform()`. I have a file called `test_learning.py` containing unit tests. When I run a unit test, I would like the code in `learning` to see the patched version of `random.uniform()`. How can I do this? Here is what I have currently.

```
import random
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

class TestLearning(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_random_belief_bit(self):
        with mock.patch('learning.random.uniform', mock_uniform):
            bit = learning.get_random_belief_bit(0.4)
            self.assertEqual(bit, 0)
```

But the test (sometimes) fails because `learning.get_random_belief_bit()` seems to be using the real `random.uniform()`.

Comment: My guess is that you have to patch `uniform` at `random`

Comment: Also you're importing `random` at your test, this would ruin the mock, why not `from random import uniform` at `learning`? ... so that you don't have to mock `random`?

Comment: @geckos what would I have to do so that "from random import uniform" imports the mocked version?

Comment: replace `import random` by `from random import uniform` and mock as `with mock.patch('learning.uniform', return_value=1) as uniform_mock`

Comment: the `as ..` part is optional but useful if you need to customize even more the mocked behavior

Answer (score 0):

Unit test solution:

`learning.py`:

```py
import random


def get_random_belief_bit(f):
    return random.uniform()
```

`test_learning.py`:

```py
import random
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
import learning


class TestLearning(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_random_belief_bit(self):
        with mock.patch('random.uniform', mock.Mock()) as mock_uniform:
            mock_uniform.return_value = 0
            bit = learning.get_random_belief_bit(0.4)
            self.assertEqual(bit, 0)
            mock_uniform.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Name                                          Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/57874971/learning.py            3      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/57874971/test_learning.py      13      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                            16      0   100%
```